# angular select not working in chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

Simple code with select options working well in firefox, but not in chrome

js:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl',  ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ["", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" ];
  $scope.currentItem = "Item 
}])
```

html:

```
<select name="se" id="se" ng-model="currentItem" size="5">
  <option ng-repeat="i in items" value="{{i}}">{{i}}</option>
</select>
```

You can see it in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qjmf3CbqQ0KvgZxwRO5b?p=preview)

If i click on an option, currentItem doesn't change.
If i press on keyboard up arrow or down arrow it works.

How I can resolve it for chrome?

Comment: it works in chrome for me

Comment: check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/viWXtjd4SLGo1vdRrIfb?p=preview) I use ng-options as opposed to ng-repeat. I think is the preferred syntax for select in angularJS

Comment: It works for me too I ve just tried it with plnkr and holds true that it works.

Comment: works in chrome for me

Comment: Jax, your plunker not worked for me in Chrome. When I click in select - currentItem not changed in right part

Answer (score 0):

I found ng-size directive in jsfiddle 
    _http://jsfiddle.net/joshkurz/DFyWX/2/
and it not working in my chrome. In firefox all right.

I no understand why...

[wrong in chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgHYl.png)